# change tracking implementation

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have an application that needs to identify what has changed on a table. Change Tracking will be suitable for my needs, but I have an assumption that I need to test (with you guys!).

I think I need to persist the last version of the changes I have obtained 'somewhere' in my application. Is this correct?How can i save it?

I will then use this in the next sync call to CHANGETABLE( ......, @last_sync_version) to obtain all the changes that have occured since I last synced.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [faq] and [ask] before asking a question. This isn't a programming question. Your question probably closed in a few minutes.

Comment: SQL Server change tracking, presumably? If so, please add that (at least) as a tag to your question.

Comment: Anyone else think these stupid hats are causing ridiculous upvotes on questions?  "This isn't a programming question" has a +3 at time of writing this.